# Content React.js won't load if i disable javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm new to react. I want to ask why my React content lost if I disable javascript in browser. and one more thing, when I `curl` my `localhost:3000` it is showing html with just script and styling and no content there. Any package or trick to fix this?

Comment: haha.. thanks sir @Ahmet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is powered by JavaScript.

If your browser does not support it (or you have disabled it) it can not evaluate your React JavaScript code and therefore display nothing.

What you can do is to write a fallback with a message to let your users know they have to enable JavaScript in order to view the page.

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view this page</noscript>
```

Place this line of code above your root element for attaching React, in most cases it will be `<div id="root"></div>`